# Parallel Computation to Solve a Set of Equation and Simplify the Solution's Expression

Tags: equation-solving, parallelization

1)I have a set of equation below :

```
E1 = g11 F01^2 + g22 F02^2 + g44 F04^2 + 2 g24 F02 F04 - G00
E2 = g00 F01^2 + g33 F13^2 - 2 g03 F01 F13 - G11
E3 = g00 F02^2 + g33 F23^2 - 2 g03 F02 F23 - G22
E4 = g11 F13^2 + g22 F23^2 + g44 F34^2 - 2 g24 F23 F34 - G33
E5 = g00 F04^2 + g33 F34^2 + 2 g03 F04 F34 - G44
E6 = -g11 F01 F13 - g22 F02 F23 + g44 F04 F34 + g24 F02 F34 - g24 F04 F23 - G03
```

g00, g11, g22, g33, g44, g03, g24, G00, G11, G22, G33, G44, and G03 had have their own expression which have been known. I want to find the solution of F01, F02, F04, F13, F23, and F34 (each of them stated as a function of g00, g11, g22, g33, g44, g03, g24, G00, G11, G22, G33, G44, and G03). Solving it with just one core took so much time because of very large output, so I'm using High Processor Computer (HPC) instead. But I never work with parallel computation before. To use HPC's multiple processor, I had tried to use `Parallelize[Solve[E1==0&&E2==0&&E3==0&&E4==0&&E5==0&&E6==0,{F01,F02,F04,F13,F23,F34}]]`, but this text appear "Cannot be parallelized; proceeding with sequential evaluation". How can I solve this equation with multiple processor which HPC has.

2)I'm pretty sure that the solutions would constructed by very large expression. So how can I use `FullSimplify` command to make it becomes simpler with multiple processor too? Thank you.

Comment: Hello. Are you ultimately going to replace `g00`, `g11`, ... by numerical values in these formulas? If not, can you indicate what you imagine doing with these formulas?

Comment: Hello, big thank's for your respond. Actually what did I have is just the algebraic expressions of g00, g11, g22, g33, g44, g03, g24, G00, G11, G22, G33, G44, and G03, not the numerical values. So what I decide to do is to solve F01, F02, F04, F13, F23, and F34  first (as a function of g00, g11, g22, g33, g44, g03, g24, G00, G11, G22, G33, G44, and G03), and then I'll replace g00, g11, ... , G44 with their original expressions.

Comment: So you need these big formulas to... construct even bigger formulas. What are you planning to do with those even bigger formulas? Plug in numbers eventually? What is the endgame?

Comment: So I try to construct a metric solution of an astrophysical object space-time curvature eventually.